Packet anomaly detection using IsolationForest
I am making a packet anomaly detection program using IsolationForest and this is what i managed to make for now. Although i am not sure if the anomalies are correct. Below is the code and the dataset i used.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/a0aj85uxhv1cs6p/training_data.csv/file
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

# Load your dataset (replace 'your_dataset.csv' with your actual file name)
df = pd.read_csv('training_data.csv')

# Select relevant features from the provided list
features = ['Total Fwd Packets', 'Total Backward Packets', 'Flow Duration', 'Total Length of Fwd Packets', 'Total Length of Bwd Packets', 'Fwd Packet Length Max', 'Fwd Packet Length Min', 'Fwd Packet Length Mean', 'Fwd Packet Length Std', 'Bwd Packet Length Max', 'Bwd Packet Length Min', 'Bwd Packet Length Mean', 'Bwd Packet Length Std', 'Flow Bytes/s', 'Flow Packets/s', 'Flow IAT Mean', 'Flow IAT Std', 'Flow IAT Max', 'Flow IAT Min', 'Fwd IAT Total', 'Fwd IAT Mean', 'Fwd IAT Std', 'Fwd IAT Max', 'Fwd IAT Min', 'Bwd IAT Total', 'Bwd IAT Mean', 'Bwd IAT Std', 'Bwd IAT Max', 'Bwd IAT Min', 'Fwd PSH Flags', 'Fwd Header Length', 'Bwd Header Length', 'Fwd Packets/s', 'Bwd Packets/s', 'Min Packet Length', 'Max Packet Length', 'Packet Length Mean', 'Packet Length Std', 'Packet Length Variance', 'FIN Flag Count', 'SYN Flag Count', 'PSH Flag Count', 'ACK Flag Count', 'URG Flag Count', 'Down/Up Ratio', 'Average Packet Size', 'Avg Fwd Segment Size', 'Avg Bwd Segment Size', 'Init_Win_bytes_forward', 'Init_Win_bytes_backward', 'act_data_pkt_fwd', 'min_seg_size_forward', 'Active Mean', 'Active Std', 'Active Max', 'Active Min', 'Idle Mean', 'Idle Std', 'Idle Max', 'Idle Min']

# Initialize the Isolation Forest model
model = IsolationForest(contamination=0.01)  # Adjust contamination based on your dataset

# Fit the model on your data
model.fit(df[features])

# Predict anomalies (1 for normal, -1 for anomalies)
predictions = model.predict(df[features])

# Create a new column in your DataFrame to store the predictions
df['Anomaly'] = predictions

# Now you can filter out the anomalies
normal_data = df[df['Anomaly'] == 1]
anomalies = df[df['Anomaly'] == -1]

# Calculate precision, recall, and F1-score
ground_truth_labels = [1] * len(normal_data) + [-1] * len(anomalies)
predicted_labels = list(predictions)
precision = precision_score(ground_truth_labels, predicted_labels)
recall = recall_score(ground_truth_labels, predicted_labels)
f1 = f1_score(ground_truth_labels, predicted_labels)

print(f"Precision: {precision:.4f}")
print(f"Recall: {recall:.4f}")
print(f"F1-score: {f1:.4f}")

# Print the number of anomalies
print(f"Number of anomalies detected: {len(anomalies)}")

# Create a scatter plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(normal_data['Flow Duration'], normal_data['Total Fwd Packets'], color='green', label='Normal Data')
plt.scatter(anomalies['Flow Duration'], anomalies['Total Fwd Packets'], color='red', label='Anomalies')
plt.xlabel('Flow Duration')
plt.ylabel('Total Fwd Packets')
plt.title('Isolation Forest Anomaly Detection')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


This is the output of the prediction:
Precision: 0.9899
Recall: 0.9899
F1-score: 0.9899
Number of anomalies detected: 3998
and the graphical:

Cool, and what is your question? What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].
